# How to access a var with "-" in PHP

Tags: php, php-5.4

For first time I found this problem, see I've a array of objetcs and I access them as follow:

```
$arrayOfObjects[$pos]->value;
```

But my problem is that one of the array values have a "-" meaning the value is `e-mail` so when I do this:

```
$arrayOfObjects[$pos]->e-mail;
```

I get an error, how do I handle this? The var can't be changed!!

Comment: what error? This is most crucial part to include

Comment: best answer is not to have object elements with hyphens in the first place. (there are solutions, but the code is ugly; best way is to avoid it completely)

Comment: `$arrayOfObjects[$pos]->{'e-mail'};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you absolutely have to have the hyphens, you can access it like:

```
$arrayOfObjects[$pos]->{'e-mail'};
```

Comment: Sometimes it can't be avoided if the data has been retrieved from a call to a remote 3rd party system

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** access a variable with a dash in it in that fashion.

Try this:

```
$arrayOfObjects[$pos]['e-mail'];
```

Comment: This is using an object like an array, which is bad practice in my opinion. But I could be wrong..